# Two Polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, contest-math, roots

I have troubling to prove this problem without any calculus Tools. It's an Olympiad Problem for High school students which says :

Is there a pair of real numbers $ (a,b) $
Such that the two polynomials $ P(x) = (x-a)^3+(x-b)^2+x $ $ , $ $ Q = (x-b)^3+(x-a)^2+x $ have all their roots in real numbers?

Can you help me?

( There's a simple solution that I came up with using derivative. But I need some simple proof which doesn't use calculus. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beacuse of simmetry we can assume that $a\geq b$

Let us prove that in this case $P$ is strictly increasing.

Take any $x,y$ such that $y>x$. Then we have:

$$ P(y)-P(x) = (y-x)\Big[ \Big(y+{1+x-3a\over 2}\Big)^2+{1\over 4}\Big(x+{1-3a\over 3}\Big)^2+{1\over 36}(24(a-b)+11) \Big]$$

We see that $P(y)>P(x)$ so $P$ is having exactly one real root.

Comment: Thank you. Really great!